# BatchUpdateException - MySQL Error 'Duplicate entry' - which key/constraint has been violated?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, exception, jdbc, constraints

The combo mysql/hibernate is creating exception stack traces like

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '7872551600-B1310955127' for key 2
```

at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ServerPreparedStatement.java:652)
   at   org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:519)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
   ... 51 more

Now what's happening is obvious. There's a table with a constraint (unique key), and this constraint has been violated.

But all the exception says that some key '2' has been violated. Is there a way to make mysql print out which constraint has been violated? or at least on which table?

Thanks
holger

Answer (score 0):

Key 2 is the second index on the table. If you have a primary key, key 2 is the first index after that.

I can't tell you which table it is, but once you figure that out if you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on that table the second index it lists is the one that was violated.